# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to join Windows AD domain

Tags: 20.04, active-directory

I am new with Ubuntu / Linux.
I am attempting to join a Ubuntu 20.04 machine to a Windows domain using the following command:

```
sudo realm join -v ad1.example.com
```

This fails with the following error:

```
root@computer:~# sudo realm join -v example.org
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.example.org
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.0.5.5
 * Successfully discovered: example.org
Password for Administrator:
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain example.org --domain-realm EXAMPLE.ORG --domain-controller 10.0.5.5 --login-type user --login-user Administrator --stdin-password
 * Using domain name: example.org
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: COMPUTER
 * Using domain realm: example.org
 * Sending NetLogon ping to domain controller: 10.0.5.5
 * Received NetLogon info from: DC01.example.org
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-ZG1Ish/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-dobebh
 ! Couldn't get kerberos ticket for: Administrator@EXAMPLE.ORG: New password cannot be zero length
adcli: couldn't connect to example.org domain: Couldn't get kerberos ticket for: Administrator@EXAMPLE.ORG: New password cannot be zero length
 ! Failed to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Failed to join the domain
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo realm join --user=Administrator -v example.org
```

And maybe:

```
kinit Administrator@EXAMPLE.ORG
```

before the `join` command.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the domain user had the box "Must change password on the next login" checked.